# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can somebody help me. I'm experiencing this error.
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined'
and it says that this is from sessionChecker.
Can someone help me how to debug or to solve this error. I'm trying to fix this for my project. i hope you can help me with this

```
export default {
name: 'payout-network-manager-table',
components: {
    AddPayOutNetworkModal,
    EditPayOutNetworkModal,
    ViewPayOutNetworkModal,
    NotesModal
},
mixins: [
    sessionChecker
],
data () {
    return {
        search_key_word: '',
        payout_networks: {},
        countries: [],
        pay_out_network_types: {},
        new_pay_out_networks: {},
        pay_out_network_id_for_view: 0,
        pay_out_network_id_for_edit: 0,
        pay_out_network_id_for_note: 0,
        country_id: '',
        submitting: false,
        token: localStorage.token,
        display: false,
    }
},
created() {
    this.getPayoutNetworks();
    Fire.$on('reloadAfterNewAmendPayOutNetwork', () => {
        this.getPayoutNetworks();
    });
},
methods: {
    getPayoutNetworks(page){
        let formData = new FormData;
        if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
            page = 1;
        }

        formData.append('search_key_word', this.search_key_word);

        axios.post('/api/payout-networks?page=' + page, formData, {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                this.display = true;
                this.payout_networks = response.data.payout_network_list;
                this.countries = response.data.countries;
                this.pay_out_network_types = response.data.pay_out_network_types;
                this.extractCountryAvailableInto();
            })
            .catch( error => {
                this.sessionChecker( error );
            });
    },
    passPayoutNetworkId (id) {
        this.pay_out_network_id_for_view = id;
    },
    passPayOutNetworkIdForEdit (id) {
        this.pay_out_network_id_for_edit = id;
    },
    passPayoutNetworkIdForNotes (id) {
        this.pay_out_network_id_for_note = id;
    },
    deletePayoutNetwork (id) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Payout Network?'))
        {           
            axios.delete('/api/payout-network', {
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    id: id
                })
            })
                .then( response => {
                    Fire.$emit('reloadAfterNewAmendPayOutNetwork');
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: response.data.message
                    });
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    this.sessionChecker( error );
                })
        }
    }
}
};
```

This is my sessionChecker. Can someone help me to solve this error.

```
export const sessionChecker = {
mixins: [
  logout
],
methods: {
    sessionChecker ( error ) {
      let title = 'Something went wrong, Please log in again';
      let wrong = false;
      if( error.response.status == 400 ) {
        title = 'Bad Request, Please log in';
        wrong = true;
      }
      if( error.response.status == 401 ) {
        title = 'Unauthorized action, Please log in';
        wrong = true;
      }
      if( error.response.status == 403 ) {        
        title = 'Forbidden, Please log in';   
        wrong = true; 
        if( error.response.data.message == 'Your email address is not verified.' ) {
          title = 'Your email address is not verified. Please verify first before we proceed';  
          wrong = false;
        }
      }
      if( error.response.status == 404 ) {
        title = 'Page not found, Please log in';
        wrong = true;
      }
      if( error.response.status == 419 ) {
        title = 'Session Expired, Please log in again, sorry for the inconvenience';
        wrong = true;
      }
      Toast.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: title
      });
      if( error.response.status != 422 ) {
        if( wrong ) {
          this.logout();
        } 
        else {
          if (this.$route.path !== '/email/resend') {
              this.$router.push({ path : '/email/resend' });
          }
        }
      }
    },
},
```

Comment: Could you provide the line number where the error is thrown ? And provide the code where you call the sessionChecker.

Comment: The error is thrown in the error response status 400

Answer (score 0):

Since `error.response` could be undefined, you should use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in order to access to `error.response.status`.

e.g: `error?.response?.status`